# Neural Network weights

Tags: matlab, neural-network

This is going to be a long question :

I have written a code in MATLAB for updating the weights of MLP with one hidden layer . Here is the code :

```
function [ weights_1,weights_2 ] = changeWeights( X,y,weights_1,weights_2,alpha )
%CHANGEWEIGHTS updates the weight matrices 
%   This function changes the weight of the weight matrix
%   for a given value of alpha using the back propogation algortihm

m = size(X,1) ;     % number of samples in the training set

for i = 1:m
    % Performing the feed-forward step 
    X_i  = [1 X(i,1:end)]    ;  % 1-by-5 input 
    z2_i = X_i*weights_1'    ;  % 1-by-4   
    a2_i = sigmoid(z2_i)     ;  % 1-by-4   
    a2_i = [1 a2_i]          ;  % 1-by-5   
    z3_i = a2_i*weights_2'   ;  % 1-by-3   
    h_i  = sigmoid(z3_i)     ;  % 1-by-3   

% Calculating the delta_output_layer 
    delta_output_layer = ( y(i)' - h_i' )...
        .*sigmoidGradient(z3_i')  ; % 3-by-1 matrix

% Calculating the delta_hidden_layer 
    delta_hidden_layer =  (weights_2'*delta_output_layer)...
        .*sigmoidGradient([1;z2_i']) ; % 5-by-1 matrix 
    delta_hidden_layer = delta_hidden_layer(2:end) ; 

% Updating the weight matrices
    weights_2 = weights_2 + alpha*delta_output_layer*a2_i ; 
    weights_1 = weights_1 + alpha*delta_hidden_layer*X_i  ;
end

end
```

Now I wanted to test it on the `fisheriris` dataset given in MATLAB which can be accesed by `load fisheriris` command . I renamed `meas` to `X` and changed `species` to a `150-by-3` matrix where each row depicts the name of species (as for example first row is `[1 0 0]`)

I compute error of the output layer using the following function :

```
function [ g ] = costFunction( X,y,weights_1,weights_2 )
  %COST calculates the error 
  %   This function calculates the error in the 
  %   output of the neural network 

  % Performing the feed-forward propogation
  m = size(X,1) ; 
  X_temp  = [ones([m 1]) X]   ;  % 150-by-5 matrix 
  z2 = X_temp*weights_1'       ; % 150-by-5-by-5-by-4 
  a2 = sigmoid(z2)       ; 
  a2 = [ones([m 1]) a2]            ; % 150-by-5
  z3 = a2*weights_2'     ; % 150-by-3
  h  = sigmoid(z3)       ; % 150-by-3

  g = 0.5*sum(sum((y-h).^2)) ; 
  g = g/m ; 
end
```

Now in the course the prof gave an example of toy network with 3 iterations , I tested this on that network and it gives the right values but when I test it on the fisheriris data the cost keeps on increasing . And I am not able to understand where it is going wrong .

Comment: what's the range of output data?

Comment: output data is a vector of the form [ x y z ] where x,y,z belong to {0,1}